# Moving a part of the code from main class to deal with readability issues

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a "Form1.cs" class where all of the proccessing happens and that file has nearly 2k line of code. **I no longer can read it properly.**

is there a way to move part of the functions to another file? an extension class? I still want to be able to call these functions from main "Form1.cs". And these functions should not have any problems reading public declared variables in main class.

```
using ...

namespace myprogram
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
       public void function1() {}
       public void function2() {}
       public void function3() {}
       public void function4() {}
    }
}
```

in the example above - what is the proper way to move function 4 to another file. Is there any other way to deal with the problem maybe?

Comment: you shouldn't just be moving them to a different file.  You should be encapsulating sections of logic into separate classes that have no knowledge of this form or its data, but that are instead utilized by it.  You're effectively asking how to drive a nail with a glass bottle most effectively.  The correct answer is to get a hammer.

Comment: As @Servy and others have alluded to, anything that is not directly related to the functioning of the form should be refactored into a separate class (perhaps even assembly) and that class should be referenced by the form.

Comment: I totally agree with that. That is what Object-Oriented programming is made for.. I have created several helper classes already but main class just keeps increasing in size! I have decided to write a code and to make my program WORK. Afterwards I will make optimizations to the code and try to stick to OOP methodology. Before that happens - I want to keep my code clean with other approaches that I can use confidently and productively.

Comment: @Alex If you're to the point where your class is so large that you can't actually effectively work on it then clearly you're already well past the point where you need to refactor out much of the code.  If you're going to take the time to do it just do it correctly from the start, rather than knowingly doing it wrong only to do it right after you've already wasted a ton of time trying to work with an unworkable mess.  The whole *point* of a well designed and modularized program is to make it easier to develop and work with.  Doing that after it's done is counter-productive.

Comment: @Servy That is true ;( Program's almost finished already so I do not expect the code to grow.. Nevertheless I still need to do the changes to the logic hence that is where partial classes will come in handy, as people suggested. P.S. I am by no means am a programmer, nor have an education as a programmer. Just self-learning & hobby mainly. OOP is on my to-learn list after this little project is finished. :) I love SO community for justified critics. Thank you for tips everyone!

Comment: I think this could be a good question for code review website. Not all 2K lines though, pick the worst method, make sure it's under 50 lines and post it on CR. People will provide their opinions and you'll get the idea how to refactor the rest. Granted, those 50 lines should be easy to read and comprehend by someone who has no background of your program and its application domain.

Comment: @Neolisk oh, I was not aware that such a website exists! Favorited!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Making all of your controls publicly visible from outside the `Form`, and then just copying code into a separate class and having it access the instance of your `Form` to manipulate the controls directly will not help you maintain your code. It'll just make things a whole new kind of difficult.

What you really want is to move your "business logic", or whatever you want to call it, into a separate class, without moving code that directly touches the UI. (Leave that code in the original `Form`.)

You said you've already got helper classes, and it sounds like you intend to go the partial class route for now, so the following may be unnecessary to reiterate (but here goes anyway...)

---

Assuming your `Form` currently looks like this:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
   public void function4()
   {
       var currentText = MyTextBox.Text;

       // Do a bunch of stuff that depends on the Text value and even manipulates it

       MyTextBox.Text = ??? // Some other value
   }

   public void SomeOtherFunction()
   {
       function4();
   }
}
```

I'd split out the functionality into a separate class, which accepts parameters from your Form and can pass values back, but absolutely does not directly reference controls on the Form that's calling it.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
   private HelperClass helper;

   public Form1()
   {
       helper = new HelperClass();
   }

   public void SomeOtherFunction()
   {
       MyTextBox.Text = helper.Function4(MyTextBox.Text);
   }
}

public class HelperClass()
{
    public string Function4(string input)  // I need a better name
    {
       // Do a bunch of stuff that depends on the input value and even manipulates it

       return ???  // Some other value, perhaps from the previous stuff you did
    }
}
```

If you need to return multiple values, there are structures for that, such as a `Tuple`, though beware this can be difficult to maintain as well:

```
public class HelperClass()
{
    public Tuple<int,string> Function4(string input)  // I need a better name ;p
    {
       // Do a bunch of stuff that depends on the input value and even manipulates it

       return Tuple.Create(200, "Success!");
    }
}
```

Or just create another small class, to create an instance of, populate with data, and return back to the calling method in your original `Form`.

Answer (score 1):

First note: **You shouldn't have 2K lines of code in the form code behind!** You should split up the logic into appropriate objects, helper classes, etc.

To answer your question: This is exactly what `partial` classes do. `Form1` is already marked partial, so just create a new file, and add:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
     //All your functions
}
```

The compiler combines all the partial classes to form one class definition.

Comment: No, this is *not* what partial classes are for.  It's exactly what partial classes do, but it's very much contrary to the reason that they exist.  They're not there to enable creation of monolithic classes.  They're there to enable classes that are partially automatically generated and partially manually defined.

Comment: @Servy Fair enough; my intention was to say: "Partial classes are for splitting code between multiple files" which is then used by VS to do the automated/manual split. I changed the wording.

Comment: @Servy: you can and you *have to* in some cases create partial class when dealing with Facade classes, managed by different people in your team, to avoid pushing conflicts. That is a natural choice and has nothing to do with automatic generation of a form, which is perfectly suitable in this case too: to create at least 2 files, which one is autogenerated and does not meant to be changed by developer. So partial class, is a tool, the meaning of which is not bond to the windows.forms in particular by any means, contrary otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new file, and add your class as a `partial` class. It's what already has been done by Visual Studio code template to keep your code and the designer code separately.

Only make sure the name of the class is the same and the namespace also has to be the same.

```
namespace myprogram
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public void function4() {}
    }
}
```

You can have your class in as many files as you want, as long as they are marked with the `partial` keyword.